# Swift method with a swift enum as parameter is not visible in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a swift Class with an enum and a method which expects a parameter of with type of the enum:

```
import SpriteKit

enum Direction: Int {
    case up = 1;
    case down = -1;
}

class ParallaxScrollingNode: SKNode {

    func addStaticBackground(name: String) {
        ...
    }

    func addParallaxBackground(imageNames: [String], yScaleFactor: CGFloat, yDirection: Direction) {
        ...
    }
```

In my Objective C class it is possible to call the first, but not the second method:

[image]

Looks like the enum is causing the issue. The method is missile, if I change the type to Int. Of course I can do this with my code, but I want to understand if this is not working in general or if I have missed something.

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: try add @objc before enum declaration

Comment: @rkyr that worked. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for someone who has simillar issue:

adding `@objc` specification before declaration makes this struct available in Objective-C world.

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).